# Language of groups (Logic)

Tags: group-theory, logic

In the language of groups:

- I have to show that if $\Gamma$ is a theory such that every finite group is a model of $\Gamma$,then there is an infinite group that is a model of $\Gamma$.
- Show that if $\varphi$ is a sentence such that every infinite group is a model of $\varphi$, then there is a finite group that is a model of $\varphi$.

I have no idea how to start and I want some hints, please ;)

Comment: For the first one, "the usual compactness argument" will work. (Have you seen this argument for the existence of non-standard models of arithmetic?). Some formulations of the upward Löwenheim-Skolem theorem will apply to this case too.

Comment: What have you learned so far in your study of logic? For instance, have you learned about ultraproducts?

Comment: The second part follows from the first one by contraposition and considering $\Gamma=\{\neg\varphi\}$.

Comment: I follow "The incompleteness phenomenom" from Goldstern and Judah, Page 119. I don't know nothing about the ultraproducts, but I know the compactness theorem

Comment: @Alopiso: To use compactness, add a fresh constant letter $c$ and new axioms $c^n\ne e$ for every $n\ge 1$. By compactness the extended theory has a model (because every finite subset of it contains only finitely many of the new axioms, so there's a sufficiently large finite order that $c$ is allowed to have). But in a model of the full extended theory $c$ must have infinite order.